# Statsd "Bad Line" error when sending UDP data using Micrometer

Tags: statsd, micrometer

When sending Statsd packages from my app to Statsd server,  we can see the following **Bad line** error in the statsd server:

```
DEBUG: Bad line: value,name in msg jdbc.connections.min:10|g|#statistic:value,name:dataSource"
```

Since I'm using the Micrometer maven dependancy of:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-statsd</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm note sure how to control this `value,name` property

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the flavor of the Statsd we used.

There are several Statsd flavors (Etsy, Datadog & Telegraf).

As we changed the configuration to be:

```
management.metrics.export.statsd.flavor=etsy
```

The graphite was no longer dropping the packets and received them correctly.